# sqlite3.OperationalError: table test has no column named python error

Tags: python, mysql-python

cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO login (login_ID, username, password) VALUES
(1, 'jguyg0', 'jhbbh'),
(2, 'fgcghj', 'mujh'),
(3, 'ffhiuh', 'aphu'),
(4, 'ugyug', 'clear'),
(5, 'knuin', 'Proae'),
(6, 'uygy', 'mats'),
(7, 'ewawez', 'fre'),
(8, 'hjbgbi', 'initive'),
(9, 'iuhui', 'Opene'),
(10, 'lhuh', 'upward');
...........................
(11, 'ajhiyg0', 'func'),
(20, 'akhikhk', 'Reverneered');

""")

```
I'm getting a no column named error and I can't seem to figure out why? I've found a few syntax error but after that it still doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not the correct code, since the create statement, a bit better formatted is:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login ( 
    login_ID int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    login_ID int(11) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(20) NOT NULL
 )
```

As you can see, you have defined `login_ID` twice which fails.

Or perhaps ithe table does not exist, or you have previously created the table and expected this new create to work. A `describe login` should tell you what its definition is, or a `drop login` to get it to work, after you have corrected the statement.

If this mysql or sqlite?

Comment: Sorry I meant to delete the twice login_ID I was just messing arounf adding a second one. I'm using mysqlite through python to make a database and menu to access certain features within the database like adding and deleting certain things

Comment: Then access the db directly though sqlite, and run `.schema login`, and post the details.

Comment: I did just realize I made a table a while ago with the same login info. Now I changed the table name and ID and I'm getting this error now.     cursor.execute("""
sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.

Comment: Then as per @pritesh, you need `executemany`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
#records or rows in a list
records = [(1, 'mmcgonagle0', 'foreground'), (2, 'fstickels1', 'multi-state'), (3, 'ffilochov2', 'approach'), ...]

#insert multiple records in a single query
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO login VALUES(?,?,?);',records);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Login_ID 10 I ended the line with a semi colon instead of a comma which makes python think I'm trying to run multiple functions instead of one. So instead of this:

(10, 'mdutnall9', 'upward-trending');
it needs to be this:
(10, 'mdutnall9', 'upward-trending'),
Something very small that's hard to notice. Once I fixed that my program ran without error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).